# Apache Webserver ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: apache, webserver

Hello I'm from Germany so excuse my bad English.

I'm running an apache webserver on port 80 and on my local network and with the ip from my wlan router I can reach the server and the website I want but I have a domain which is linked to a dyndns service which takes the ip from my router and changes it to a subdomain.

My problem is, I linked the domain to the subdomain and the subdomain to the dyndns of my router and now if I enter the domain in my internet browser I get the message ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

Can somebody help me please? 
I searched In google but I didnt found anything usefull

Answer (score 0):

You should do a port forward if you working behind router. When someone types the URL in browser it will send user to IP, simply it will send request to your router but router should listen the request and send request back to your local computer without interrupting any firewall instance.

Go to router setting and you will find a option of Port Forward, just add the Port no and select the local computer ip (could be 192.168....) and save it then reboot router. Should Work....

If not working even though then try disabling your local computer firewall and check...

Comment: i've done all of this but it wont work... i added the port 80 and 443 to my router and to the firewall of my pc but it dont work and the portforwarding is already working but the forwarding from the domain to the dyndns service and then to my router dont work

Comment: May i know your domain & IP? So i can tell you help you with this.

Comment: Do you also need the password and username to the admin account of my pc? 

Comment: By the way, new domainhoster that includes a dyndns and everything works dine till now